# Infinite Variance of Harmonic Mean Estimator of Marginal Likelihood of Data

Tags: bayesian, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood, computational-statistics

If *y* denotes the data and *t* denotes set of parameters, then the marginal likelihood is

[image]

Here, [image] is a proper prior, *f(y|t)* denotes the (conditional) likelihood and *m(y)* is used to denote the marginal likelihood of data *y*. The harmonic mean estimator of marginal likelihood is expressed as

[image]

, where [image] is set of MCMC draws from posterior distribution [image].

This estimator is unstable due to possible occurrence of *t* with a small likelihood which influences the result because [image] is often not square integrable. Hence the estimator may have infinite variance. [Source : Newton and Raftery (1994), P -21; DiCiccio et al. (1997), P - 905]

**Question:** I am not being able to understand or visualize the situations where [image] may not be square integrable and the estimator may end up in having infinite variance. Can you help me to understand this (may be with an example) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is well-detailed in Radford Neal's highly popular blog post ["The Harmonic Mean of the Likelihood: Worst Monte Carlo Method Ever"](https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/17/the-harmonic-mean-of-the-likelihood-worst-monte-carlo-method-ever/). It contains this Normal-Normal example:

```
harmonic.mean.marg.lik <- function (x, s0, s1, n)
   { post.prec <- 1/s0^2 + 1/s1^2
     t <- rnorm(n,(x/s1^2)/post.prec,sqrt(1/post.prec))
     lik <- dnorm(x,t,s1)
     1/mean(1/lik)
   }
```

This corresponds to a Normal N$(\theta,\sigma_1^2)$ `dnorm(x,t,s1)` likelihood and to a Normal N$((\sigma_1^{-2}+\sigma_2^{-2})^{-1}\sigma_2^{-1},(\sigma_1^{-2}+\sigma_2^{-2})^{-1})$ `rnorm(n,(x/s1^2)/post.prec,sqrt(1/post.prec))` posterior, induced by a Normal N$(0,\sigma_2^2)$ prior. As shown in this entry, non-sensical approximations occur:

```
   > set.seed(1)
   > harmonic.mean.marg.lik(2,1000,1,10^7)
   [1] 0.0791889
   > true.marg.lik(2,1000,1)
   [1] 0.0003989413
```